# Ajax/UpdatePanel alternative? (JQUERY? JSON?)

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, updatepanel

I am looking for an alterntive to AJAX/UpdatePanel for my ASP .Net application.

Currently, all my pages use an UpdatePanel containing a FormView, ListView or usually one Formview and many Listviews (one on each tab inside a TabPanel).

We are experiencing issues with Server timeouts and I realize it is probably because I really didn't understand AJAX all that well and simply embedded all these FormViews and ListViews inside an UpdatePanel "blindly"... (My thread describing these issues if you are interested is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132712/why-does-my-new-net-4-0-ef-application-randomly-lock-up).)

As I am reading more about UpdatePanel/AJAX, some suggest using JQuery/JSON instead. I am looking for recommendations and good resources on using either (any) of these technolgies.

I simply want to minimize the amount of "page flicker" when a page is refreshed. At this point I don't want to move away from the FormView and ListView controls (they are bound to data via the Entity Framework using EntityDataSources and I probably will change those to ObjectDataSources, but that shouldn't really have much of an impact on which "partial page update method" I choose).

At this point, I am simply looking for the pros and cons of UpdatePanel versus jQuery or any other competing technology that will allow my pages to do partial rendering.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: At a Microsoft conference I attended, a speaker said Ajax is being phased out. It'll be there, but Microsoft has stopped active development.